# How can I configure username and user group when using presto-cli?

Tags: presto

I am trying to impersonate a presto query using presto-cli.

I am running presto-cli with the --user option e.g.

`presto-cli --catalog hive --schema default --user user1`

This is impersonating the query as user1. Is there any way to add a user group information? e.g

username : **user1**

group : **group1**

Comment: User's session in Presto contains username information but there is no concept of user group at this level. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to apply security controls using EMRFS roles (use Amazon EMR)

Comment: What if Presto is configured with LDAP? Will it assume the group information?

Comment: Did you find any answer to this?